# Firebug causes Firefox to be unresponsive

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I'm a beginner web developer. I often use Firebug to debug my JavaScript.

Problem is that there are some script files from my page's UI that have a lot of code and this causes my web browser to be unresponsive, i.e. I get a dialog saying the script is unresponsive. Basically this happens when I am within Firebug's *Script* panel.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Have you tried to click on "Continue" instead of terminate it? Sometimes JS takes so much time to complete a task that the browser thinks it is blocked (or in an infinite loop) and prompts you to stop it

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the 'Unresponsive script' dialog and maybe provide some code, so the problem can be reproduced? If it just happens when Firebug is enabled or the dialog shows a script within Firebug itself, you should better report that to the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug).

Comment: @Pablo yes this actually works but still this happens fairly often and is really annoying. What's more I don't usually work on UI scripts nevertheless they are loaded first before my custom .js. Also after page reloading I got lots of errors where even using ,,continue" didn't work. 

I copied the errors:
chrome://firebug/content/debugger/script/sourceTool.js:818

chrome://firebug/content/lib/trace.js:55

I guess this is only partially related to the question I asked before because these are from firebug but still they crash the browser after reload. I have to use Firebug for debugging so...

Comment: As a workaround you can try using Chrome (the browser :P) and its developer tool. It's a clone of the Firebug extension, but is built in and that makes it a bit faster and reliable for certain circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried finding solution to this problem and nothing.

As for the answer I think the best was posted by @Pablo(can't assign answer to comment unfortunately) and it is simply trying out Google Chrome console. None of the problems I mentioned exists here.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem debugging some of our older scripts that make extensive use of the `eval()` function.
This causes many scripts to be displayed within the [Script Location Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu). (Each dynamically generated script is represented there.)

A possible solution, given that it was caused by the number of files in my instance, might be to see if you can bypass the problem entirely by utilizing fewer source files for the same code. Using a 'built' version of whatever frameworks you use might alleviate the problem. (Particularly if they still are debug-able in a built form.)

If that does not work, you might try debugging using Firefox' built-in debugger (available via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. (Or switch to another browser to do the debugging, but that is obviously a far less desirable solution.)

Comment: The display of the 'Unresponsive script' dialog is unrelated to the number of eval()'ed scripts, it is just related to the execution time of those scripts.